# Spring com Web Container Java ou Application Server?

Tags: java, spring, application-server, web-container

Why in some projects people use Spring with Application Server?

I see someone questions when people using spring with Application Server.

Spring has implementation of your needs (Security, Data, Cloud ...). And those needs work perfectly on a Web Container (Tomcat, Jetty ...), right?

What are the benefits of using Spring with Tomcat or a WildFly, for example?

I've heard that Application Server supports a much larger load than Web Container, Myth, or Truth?

Comment: Tomcat can handle the JDBC connection for you instead of Spring as well as configure session timeouts. Those are the big ones that come to my mind right away

Comment: That is good. But is not necessary spring to do this.